# Does Program-o uses NLP ?

Tags: chatbot, aiml, program-o

I am trying to make chat bot. I searched for some solutions and programs to help me. 
Can someone tell me if Program-o uses natural language processing? 
I have searched on google but i didn't find the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Program-O is basically the engine that uses recursive pattern-matching on AIML to find a suitable response.

The answer given here explains in a bit more detail [NLP in AIML](http://knytetrypper.proboards.com/thread/285/nlp-aiml)

The pertinent paragraph being:

> If by "natural language processing" you mean what is commonly called a "learning bot," the ALICE (AIML) bot does not meet the definition. The ALICE program (whose "brain" is the AIML scripting language) is a pattern-matching program. It searches a fairly large database - usually about 40,000 entries - for a phrase or term that matches one in the input, then selects a reply from the set designated by the closest match. It neither writes to its own files or generates spontaneous output. It doesn't "learn" by itself. Any changes or new information must be hard-coded into the AIML files by the botmaster.